Running Azure function v4 locally with Kafka
I have an Azure function that is triggered by an event hub. Since event hubs cannot be emulated, I would like to use Kafka while working locally and once deployed to the cloud use the event hub name space instead.
I cannot figure out how to register an azure function correctly with kafka using typescript and Azure function version4 . I have looked into the typescript interfaces and I cannot find kafka mentioned anywhere. All online examples only deal with Azure function v3 and not v4. Any ideas how to accomplish this?
My docker compose file:
version: '3.4'
services:
  storage:
    container_name: storage
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    ports:
       - "10000:10000"
       - "10001:10001"
       - "10002:10002"
    volumes:
       - vol_storage:/data mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.9.2
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
      ZOO_PORT_NUMBER: 2181
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.7.1
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CLUSTER_NAME: cluster_dev
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:19092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://20.64.115.37:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
      KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS: user
      KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS: password
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: cluster_dev
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:19092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
      AUTH_TYPE: "LOGIN_FORM"
      SPRING_SECURITY_USER_NAME: user
      SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  vol_cosmos:
  vol_storage:


My azure function
import {
  type InvocationContext,
  app
} from '@azure/functions';
import { Config } from '../config/index.js';


export async function messageLogged (
  message: string,
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<void> {
  context.log(message);
}

/**
 * While developing do not connect to eventhub. Instead we should use an kafka.
 */
if (!Config.isLocalDev) {
  app.eventHub('messageLogged', {
    connection: '',
    eventHubName: Config.eventHub.topic,
    cardinality: Config.eventHub.cardinality,
    consumerGroup: Config.eventHub.consumerGroup,
    handler: messageLogged
  });
} else {
  /**
   * How to connect to kafka?
   */
}


Have you tried to use KafkaJS?

@thedethfox You can use Azure EventHub.

Azure eventhub can be used to trigger  local Azure function

Microsoft has introduced Event hub emulator which can be either install locally or run as a docker image. The repo can be found here
Run via docker compose
Here is a basic docker compose file that runs it as a container:
version: '3.4'
services:
  storage:
    container_name: storage
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    ports:
       - "10000:10000"
       - "10001:10001"
       - "10002:10002"
    volumes:
       - vol_storage:/data mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
  db:
    container_name: cosmosdb
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest"
    tty: true
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 2G
    cpu_count: 2
    environment:
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=1
      - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
    ports:
       - "8081:8081"
       - "8900:8900"
       - "8901:8901"
       - "8979:8979"
       - "10250:10250"
       - "10251:10251"
       - "10252:10252"
       - "10253:10253"
       - "10254:10254"
       - "10255:10255"
       - "10256:10256"
       - "10350:10350"
    volumes:
       - vol_cosmos:/data/db

  evh:
      container_name: "eventhubs-emulator"
      image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-messaging/eventhubs-emulator:latest"
      volumes:
        - "./eventhub-emulator.config.json:/Eventhubs_Emulator/ConfigFiles/Config.json"
      ports:
        - "5672:5672"
      environment:
        BLOB_SERVER: storage
        METADATA_SERVER: storage
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      depends_on:
        - storage

volumes:
  vol_cosmos:
  vol_storage:

Config and topic managment
The emulator does not come with GUI for topic and consumer group management. Instead, this is done using a config file. The reference of the config file in the docker compose file is defined by the file name eventhub-emulator.config.json.
Here is an example:
Please note that the log option LoggingConfig accepts two values File and console.
{
  "UserConfig": {
    "NamespaceConfig": [
      {
        "Type": "EventHub",
        "Name": "emulatorNs1",
        "Entities": [
          {
            "Name": "topic_eventhub_1",
            "PartitionCount": "1",
            "ConsumerGroups": [
              {
                "Name": "consumer_group_1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "topic_eventhub_2",
            "PartitionCount": "1",
            "ConsumerGroups": [
              {
                "Name": "consumer_group_2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "LoggingConfig": {
      "Type": "File"
    }
  }
}

Connection string:
To connect to it using an azure function use the connection string

Endpoint=sb://localhost;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SAS_KEY_VALUE;UseDevelopmentEmulator=true;

SDK
As of summer 24, the SDK cannot connect to the emulator and a manual update of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs is required.
In order to perform the update, the dot net SDK is required. Once installed issue the following command:
func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs --version 6.3.0

Finally, edit the host.json file by removing this section:
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }

